# How to postiton right column over left in responsive layout?

Tags: html, css

I have a layout with a left and right column within a row.  After researching, I was able to make the image responsive and the right column is indeed on top, however in the full screen view the left column wants to remain under the right.

Here is the code and css

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 main pull-right rightslide">
<img src="images/slideright.jpg"  
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-left leftslide">
<div class="lefttext">
Full Service Marketing and Advertising Solutions with <strong>Guaranteed Results</strong>
</div>
</div>
</div>

and the css for the right and left slide 
.rightslide {
display:block;
max-width:100%;
float:right;
}
.rightslide img {
width:100%;
}
.leftslide {
display:block;
float:left;
}
.lefttext {
font-size:52px;
}
```

.[The url](http://chrchcol.byethost15.com)

Answer (score 0):

It is because one element is inside to another
use inspect element and also you forgot close image tag

Just close the image tag and it will work

`<img src="images/slideright.jpg" />`

it makes the bug and write one element inside another

Comment: Wow, thank you!  That fixed it.  Lesson learned, always debug first.

Comment: Hahaha, no problem, @ChrisCollins if it is the answer, please mark it as an asnwer,thank you :p

Comment: @ChrisCollins i will really appreciate mark this as the answer if it is the answer for you of course(the grey  arrow in my answer left side) i am trying to making a reputation here ;)